# How to list paths through DAG in Scala

Tags: scala, tree

I have a DAG of words with the following type: `HashMap[String, Set[String]]`. I want to build up a collection of all the paths through the graph. But the method I've written doesn't behave like I expect at all:

```
def buildChain(wordGraph: HashMap[String, Set[String]], path: ListBuffer[String], accumChains: ListBuffer[ListBuffer[String]]): ListBuffer[ListBuffer[String]] = {
  val children = wordGraph(path.last)

  for (word <- children) {
    path += word
    if (wordGraph.keySet.contains(word)) buildChain(wordGraph, path, accumChains)
    else accumChains += path
  } 

  return accumChains
}
```

When I pass in this graph:

`Map("chow" -> Set("how", "cho", "cow"), "how" -> Set("ho", "ow"), "cho" -> Set("ho"), "cow" -> Set("ow"))`

I expect to get:

`ListBuffer(ListBuffer("chow", "how", "ho"), ListBuffer("chow", "how", "ow"), ListBuffer("chow", "cho", "ho"), ListBuffer("chow", "cow", "ow"))`

when I start at "chow".

Instead I'm getting this:

`ListBuffer(ListBuffer(chow, how, ho, ow, cho, ho, cow, ow), ListBuffer(chow, how, ho, ow, cho, ho, cow, ow), ListBuffer(chow, how, ho, ow, cho, ho, cow, ow), ListBuffer(chow, how, ho, ow, cho, ho, cow, ow))`

and I can't figure out why. I'm sure it's simple, but I'm just missing it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution, I changed a little bit about the param types as I think immutable types are good enough:

```
def _buildChain(wordGraph: Map[String, Set[String]], path: String): List[List[String]] = { 
  wordGraph.get(path) match {
    case Some(w) =>  w.toList.flatMap(_buildChain(wordGraph, _).map(path :: _)) 
    case None =>  List(List(path))
  }
}

def buildChain(wordGraph: Map[String, Set[String]], path: List[String]): List[List[String]] = path.flatMap(_buildChain(wordGraph, _)) 


val a = _buildChain( Map("chow" -> Set("how", "cho", "cow"), "how" -> Set("ho", "ow"), "cho" -> Set("ho"), "cow" -> Set("ow")), "chow")
println(a)
val b = buildChain( Map("chow" -> Set("how", "cho", "cow"), "how" -> Set("ho", "ow"), "cho" -> Set("ho"), "cow" -> Set("ow")), List("chow", "how"))
println(b)
```

The output is:

```
List(List(chow, how, ho), List(chow, how, ow), List(chow, cho, ho), List(chow, cow, ow))


List(List(chow, how, ho), List(chow, how, ow), List(chow, cho, ho), List(chow, cow, ow), List(how, ho), List(how, ow))
```

Comment: Can you help me parse what's happening in your case statement? I'm pretty new to Scala, so I'm not sure what the `w` is bound to?

Comment: Also what does the `_` represent here?

Comment: w is the value of wordGraph[path], which is a set and and then converted to list, then we generate the path again for each the values in w, and append the current path to the beging of the result. The flatMap is important to flatten a List[List[List]] to List[List]

Comment: _ is a commonly used in scala as ignored param. Such as : List(1, 2, 3) foreach (println(_))

Comment: So the `_buildChain(wordGraph, _)` is receiving a null value for `path`?

Comment: It is not null, it is the item in the Set. The syntax is just to ignore the param name, which is the same as `x => _buildChain(wordGraph, x)`

Comment: Thanks for your help! BTW I think the outer method could be simplified a little bit: 

def buildChain(wordGraph: Map[String, Set[String]], path: String): List[List[String]] = _buildChain(wordGraph, path)

Answer (score 2):

When you execute the line `path += word` for each `word` in `children`, you are appending to the same buffer, which thus just grows to hold all the children (and the same buffer is then added multiple times to `accumChains`). You want to generate a new sequence for each word. May I suggest using immutable lists here?